# Не могу подключить ссылку System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#

Подключил System.Windows.Forms.VisualStudio 15.0.dll, но все равно не распознает using System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Почему Вы уверены что не распознает? Стоит описывать в вопросе ошибку или сообщение которое свидетельствует о неудаче. А то так долго можно гадать что там у Вас на самом деле творится.

Comment: Попробуй создать новый проект,у меня было подобное

Comment: для .NET Core проектов это делается так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1518938/373567, только там UseWPF, а вам надо UseWindowsForms

Answer (score 1):

Точно то выбрал?

Нужно выбрать `System.Windows.Forms`

[image: Скрин]

> Стоял .NET Standard, необходимо заменить на .NET Framework.

Comment: Так не могу выбрать. Пишет "Никакие сборки .NET не найдены"

Comment: Скинь скриншот всего окна

Comment: У тебя .NETStandard 2.0, измени на .NET Framework 2+, желательно 4.x+

Comment: Процесс обновления уже идет. А после будет нормально работать?

Comment: Да, System.Windows.Forms доступна в .NET Framework.

Comment: В настройках проекта измени на .NET Framework или создай новый проект с ним.

Comment: Зачем советовать устаревшие фреймворки, когда в том же .NET 6 это делается простым добавлением параметра в .csproj файл?