# Как исправить ошибку : Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, wpf, юнит-тесты, .net-6

Решил протестить основной проект (Net Core 6.0 wpf) создал тест MsTest подключил ссылку к основному проекту написал тест и он выдает ошибку

```
TestAdminAuthorization
   Источник: UnitTest1.cs строка 139
   Длительность: 1,4 с

    Сообщение: 
    Метод теста TestFoods.UnitTest1+AuthorizationTests.TestAdminAuthorization создал исключение: 
    System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution..
    
      Трассировка стека: 
    AuthorizationTests.TestAdminAuthorization()
    AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
    AuthorizationTests.TestAdminAuthorization()
```

В чем может быть проблема? Основной проект работает нормально использую VS 2022 ссылку пробывал добавлять но он пишет она не действительна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сборка WPF в .NET Core и выше подключается не через ссылку, а через свойство `<UseWPF>` в `.csproj` файле.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
  <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```